# How to strip non-alphabetic, spaces and numeric characters from a string?

Tags: php, regex

How can I use php and regex to strip all `non-alphabetic`, `spaces` and all `numeric` from a string?

I've tried this:

```
$input = "Hello - World 12";
$output = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/", "", $input);
```

Wanted output: `HelloWorld`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$output = preg_replace('/[\W\d_]/i', '', $input);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use,

```
$output = preg_replace("~[\W0-9_]~", "", $input);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this expression:

```
$answer = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z]/", '', $input);
```

This will remove any character which are not from:

```
A-Z
a-z
```

To remove any of white spaces:

```
$string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $answer);
```

Comment: I also want to remove all numeric characters.

Comment: Answer updated, please check.

Comment: Thank you, but yet it doesn't remove the spaces, is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the 0-9 and \s from your regex like so:

```
$input = "Hello - World 12";
$output = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]/", "", $input);
```

Now you are checking for every character which is not (`^`) lowercase a-z or uppercase a-z. Than you are replacing that character with nothing `""`.